# run yamllint command line using python

Tags: python, yaml

I want to run yamllint(yaml_file) using subprocess module in python .

I know there is another module to call yamllint in python , but I want to do it using subprocess

```
 lint='yamllint("%s")'%(args.yaml)
 print(lint)

 p=subprocess.Popen(lint,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 stdoutdata,stderr=p.communicate()
 if stderr:
            print(stderr)
            print("Please check YAML format")
            quit()
```

This gives me an error : b'/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"delete.yaml"\'\n/bin/sh: -c: line 0:`yamllint("delete.yaml")\'\n'

Please help me understand what is wrong in this

Answer (score 0):

The syntayx to start yamllint from a shell is "yamllint " - not "yamllint()". But for security reasons you should not use a shell to start yaml. Just pass an array of the expressions:

```
lint=["yamllint", args.yaml]
p=subprocess.Popen(lint,shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But  please note that your test on sterr does not work. You will have to work on that, too.

Comment: I got an error when I tried this : error: the following arguments are required: FILE_OR_DIR\n'

Comment: Looks like its not picking up the file name passed